# ipad screen messed up responsive design

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design

I have a question regarding responsive desing on tablets:

The goal is to have 2 or 3 divs below each other, 100% height so they look like full-screen pages. When visiting my responsive website (work in progress) on an iPad everything looks fine. But as soon as you turn the device, some unnecessary margins start to appear and the device will zoom in on the content.

My question:

Is this normal, or did I miss a few lines of code?

Edit: forgot to add the site http://www.danielsneijers.com/

Comment: try <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />

Comment: thanks, seems i forgot the maximum-scale value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug with iOS and there is a workround available: http://filamentgroup.com/lab/a_fix_for_the_ios_orientationchange_zoom_bug/

Wilst setting a maximum scale in the viewport will get round this, it also disables zooming on all devices which is very bad for accessibility and means your website is more likely to have issues with future devices.